# Property that is associated with a foreign key is not set when reading the entity from the db

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I am using the Code First approach with EF 6.X.
There are two entities and a context:

```
class Product
{
   long Id { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
   ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
}

class ProductCategory
{
   long Id { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
}

class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
}
```

As I am using the expected naming conventions I am able to create the database from the model, add items and read them back - without data annotations and without using the fluent API.
Well, actually, I do use the fluent API to set up HasMaxLength on some properties, but that configuration code does not set up keys or foreign keys.

The important point here is that when calling the following:

```
Product product = context.Products.Find(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

the product's ProductCategory is correctly populated with a ProductCategory instance.
The problem I am encountering is that this behavior seems not to be consistent.

Within a WebApi controller I create an instance of the ProductContext class and read perform the same operation as in the snippet above.
The result is a Product that is correctly instantiated, but whose ProductCategory property is set to null.

Can anyone explain what the difference might be between these two usages? What are the prerequisites for my DbContext derived context to be able to convert the foreign key entry in the Product table to an instance of the ProductCategory class?

Comment: Add some more relevant code here. How do you configure EF Context ?

Comment: *the product's ProductCategory is correctly populated with a ProductCategory instance* -- `ProductCategory` is not lazy loading (it's not `virtual`) so it can only be populated if it was loaded before in the context. Check carefully in which aspects the two pieces of code differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity framework by default doesn't load related objects when loading object from DB. You must:

**Use `Include` statement:**

```
context.Products.Include(p => p.ProductCategory).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1);
```

**Or use lazy loading by marking your navigation property as `virtual`:**

```
class Product
{
   long Id { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
   virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Then your `ProductCategory` is loaded first time you will touch it.

**Or load reference manually:**

```
context.Entry(product).Reference(p => p.ProductCategory).Load();
```